# Do internal annotations on user accounts fall under the GDPR?

Tags: gdpr

In a platform such as Stack Exchange or any other *moderated* forum-type site, in which specific moderators have access to account information that regular users don't, and in which said moderators may make *annotations* on an account for the purposes of helping moderation, is the GDPR relevant to said annotations in any way? "Annotation" here simply means any arbitrary text message a moderator or employee may attach to an account for future reference, e.g. to keep track of continued bad behaviour.

Does the account holder have any rights to see said annotations or request their deletion or alteration? In practice that would be counter productive for the moderators as it would inhibit their ability to moderate the platform efficiently.

Would any other sort of metadata, like say, encryption keys generated for and attached to the account, be subject to the same kind of disclosure? If not, why would it be different?

Comment: Several opinions on this may be found in the comments under the answer that sparked this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386385/828193

Answer (score 6):

IANAL.

(1) GDPR is certainly relevant.

(2) This is certainly "personal data" under the definition in GDPR article 4.

(3) Maintaining this data is probably lawful under article 6 sections 1(a) (consent) - provided that the Terms and Conditions of the site make clear that the user by signing up is consenting to this information being held

(3) There is certainly an obligation under article 14 to disclose that the information exists, and to say how it used.

(4) Article 15 says that data subjects are entitled to see the information and know what recipients or categories of recipient have access to the information (I don't know whether it's enough to just say "moderators", or whether the moderators need to be identified).

(5) I can't see any reasons why the obligations under articles 16, 17, and 18 regarding rectification, erasure, and restriction of processing aren't relevant.

This is *exactly* the kind of situation that GDPR is designed to address. If you're restricting the service available to particular users based on a record of their behaviour or on judgements made by moderators, then they absolutely have a right to know, and a right of redress.

Comment: How about the conflict this creates with being able to maintain the service? If moderators annotate accounts with "probably sock puppet account of XYZ" and such, and the account holder can see this information and know to avoid using their sock puppet accounts as they've been "found out"… that makes this kind of moderation more or less impossible. That's just "tough luck"?

Comment: Find me the exemption under GDPR that applies, don't just tell me that you think there should be one.

Comment: For starters, I cannot clearly interpret article 4 as clearly saying that this *is* "personal data". I would say it highly depends on what exactly that annotation says. If it says "this is John Doe", well, yes, sure… If the annotation just says "account tends to be active at midnight", how is that data either personal or identifies the person in any way? Seems very grey-zoney to me.

Comment: The question is about "annotations on an account" and I was assuming that account holders were identifiable natural persons. You can question that assumption if you like, but in many cases it will be true.

Comment: AFAIU whether the account holder is a natural person is somewhat besides the point. Article 14 says "Information to be provided where personal data have not been obtained from the data subject". Is an annotation created by a moderator "personal data" (as described in article 4), and does it therefore need to be provided? IMO at best the definition is murky.

Comment: This analysis is not convincing.

Comment: @deceze "the account holder can see this information and know to avoid using their sock puppet accounts" - mission accomplished, surely?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Not if they start using other, as of yet undetected accounts.

Comment: When a patient requests his/her mental health records, the professional treating it can sanitize it. Both to protect the professional evaluation notes ("when I ask him about his school years he is vague, maybe he is lying about what he tells") and to protect other stakeholders privacy ("I have had an interview with the patient's mother and she says that he always has behaved strangely..."). IIRC there is clause explaining that GDPR rights cannot be used to violate the rights of other people.

Comment: Consent is extremely unlikely to be the basis for this kind of information, it's much more likely to be legitimate interests.  Disclosure would likely to be refused on the lawful grounds that this would adversely affect the rights and freedoms of others.

Comment: I cannot see any reasonable court deciding that StackExchange has a right to discriminate between users based on information it holds that it refuses to disclose to those users. That's exactly the kind of behaviour which GDPR is intended to prevent. It would probably be admissible if the data is objective and verifiable and used in an undiscriminating way, but holding casual and unverified speculation entered by moderators is completely out of order.

Comment: @deceze I guess your confusion about whether it is personal data comes from the fact that you refer to accounts instead of users. "deceze is a sockpuppet of notDeceze" is still information about you, the person behind the account deceze, and thus personal information.

Comment: @Magisch So wouldn't it at the very least heavily depend on what exactly is in that annotation? If the information by itself, or even in conjunction with some other not-directly-personal-information does not allow anyone to personally identify you, how is that "personal data"? Again, an example of that would be an annotation like "frequently quibbles in comments", or something along those lines. That would "identify" about half the userbase of SO. So at the very least, annotations could be selectively sanitised if requested (see @SJuan), no?

Comment: I'm looking for some more reasoning on Micheal's point #2; just "certainly" is not really convincing in itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95445/discussion-between-magisch-and-deceze).

Answer (score 4):

Such account annotations are clearly personal data, and would have to be disclosed as part of a data subject access request.

Personal data is any information relating to an identified or identifiable data subject (cf GDPR Art 4(1)). This means personal data does not only cover PII such as names or contact info, but also any information linked with that information. Account annotations are clearly linked with that account and thus are part of the account holder's personal data.

The Art 15 right to access is *not conditional*. The data controller must provide all personal data, and has no basis to withhold any personal data. The GDPR overrides any confidentiality policies that the controller may otherwise use.

The GDPR knows the following limitations to the right of access:

- Per Art 15(4), access to the personal data “shall not adversely affect the rights and freedoms of others.”
- Per Art 12(5), a controller can refuse to act on “manifestly unfounded or excessive” requests.
- The data subject's identity must be reasonably verified for a request. Where the identity cannot be verified, a request can be declined.

Verification that the person making the request is the data subject for that account won't be a problem. Arguing that such a request would be excessive is also highly dubious.

But the rights and freedoms of others do offer a possible argument. For example, this basis has been used in one case to deny access to CCTV recordings from a Metro system, on the basis that disclosing the location of cameras would threaten security and therefore the freedom of other Metro users. But this public security interest would need to be balanced against the data subject's interest to access, which would depend on the data subject's reason for requesting access. To which degree such arguments are acceptable depends primarily on the responsible supervisory authorities.

Here, it might be possible to exclude account notes where those notes involve other data subjects as well. But that would have to be decided on a case by case basis. Neither the complete inclusion nor the blanket exclusion of notes would seem legal. The decision would be down to the data controller's Data Protection Officer.

Similar arguments apply to erasure or rectification of the data, but those rights are more limited than the right to access. Whether a right to erasure exists depends also on the legal basis under which the personal data was collected. In case of legitimate interest, there might be an overriding legitimate interest to keep that data and deny the data subject's erasure request.

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory Disclaimer: Not a lawyer, and not an expert in GDPR law and regulations.

I got curious about this and did some digging. There are certain exemptions to the right to access in specific member states. For the argument here I used the UK as the relevant member state because that's where SE's EU liaison is located.

The analysis here cited is from the [Information Comissioner's Office](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/exemptions/).

### No general exemption for trade secrets.

Generally, there are no exemptions for the GDPR Article 15 "Right to Access". That means, absent specific other exemptions in national law, every single bit of personal data (meaning: data related to the account) would have to be disclosed, even if the disclosure of such data would prejudice or reveal trade secrets of the data controller. [The European Trade Secrets Directive (2016/943/EU)](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32016L0943) specifically does not make an allowance to use it to prejudice data access requests.

### Annotations that contain PI of other users

On a case-by-case basis, the Data Protection Act of 2018 provides a [specific exemption](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/exemptions/) for personal data that contains personal data or the identities of other data subject.

In this case that would probably apply to annotations that reference another user, such as "Magisch has conspired with TotallyNotMagisch to promote the MagischWeb Service across their answers".

For such annotations, disclosure could probably be refused on a case-by-case basis based on the right to privacy of the other person.

### Is it even PI?

This is an interesting one, because from a plain reading of the law, obviously annotations specifically about a user would amount to personal information about that user. However, a recent ECJ decision has made that distinction less clear cut. Recently, in *YS, M, and S v Minister for Immigratie, Integratie en Asiel* the court held that the results of an agent processing a person's data (a form with recommendations and legal analysis concerning someone's application for residency in the netherlands) was not strictly speaking personal data and did not have to be disclosed as part of a Right to Access Request.

I don't pretend to understand the full context and preliminary decision here, but it seems to me that the question of how much of the results of PI processing is itself PI is still not exhaustively decided in litigation and thus not set in stone. I wouldn't be surprised if further exemptions are carved from the definition for similar situations.

### Broad Language and infringing on the rights of others

Article 15. 4) states:

> The right to obtain a copy referred to in paragraph 3 shall not
>   adversely affect the rights and freedoms of others.

I have no idea how that affects what I wrote above, and couldn't find any court decisions or challenges from that angle, but I would infer from this that in specific situations where a request is made in obviously bad faith with intent to damage or harass moderators making the annotation or moderators in general, this could be invoked to deny specific parts or whole annotations from disclosure on a case-by-case basis.

Further, it would probably be possible to argue that revealing specific annotations could negatively impact and damage the governance of stack exchange and the volunteer work of its moderators.

I'm not sure how far that goes and again haven't found any legal analysis pertaining to it but it seems like something to consider at the end.

Answer (score -3):

Well... I will try to make mine a simple one, for in this specific case (IMHO) a long answer with detailed mention to GDPR articles will just confuse everyone.

Any type of Processing of Personal Data (Gathering; Storing; Access; Processing; Sharing) happens under a given "purpose" and "scope" that needs to observe by a documented applicable and arguable Lawful Base.

Therefore, if and where "annotations" (internal or external) contain Personal Data the Data Subject must be informed about that.

If those annotations are vital for the Service being rendered and the Data Subject may oppose to them (which then again it may not even be the case), then the DAta Subject must be informed that opting out/ opposing to the annotation will render the Service undeliverable.

In terms of a DSAR, it is not mandatory to inform the Data Subject about what the annotations read... just the type of Personal Data registered on those and that only if it is not registered somewhere else...

Yet I understand that annotations may contain new Personal Data that derives from processing (e.g. this guy does not like XXXXXX)... in that case you do not need to share what is written with the Data Subject, you may just inform that it is Data which characterizes preferences about topic XXXXX for it is relevant in order to focus information to be conveyed under the scope of the Services.

This is not a complicated topic...

Now the Lawful Base may likelly be Legitimate Interest yet it depends (as always from context, meaning "purpose" and "scope")

Comment: “In terms of a DSAR, it is not mandatory to inform the Data Subject about what the annotations read” – but if the annotations are personal data (otherwise you wouldn't have to inform the data subject about them) then wouldn't you also have to give the data subject a copy in response to their DSAR? As written, this answer seems to go against the GDPR's actual requirements.

Comment: If the annotations do not contain Personal Data... read the entire text please....

Comment: "if the annotations do not contain personal data" - They're annotations attached to a user's account. They *are* personal data.

Comment: Magish again, if ther eis no Personal Data it means the anotation does not add to the profiling of the individual, hence it does not matter if they are related or not to the user account.